# "Collection NSArray was mutated while being enumerated" in Release Mode only

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm getting the `"Collection NSArray was mutated while being enumerated"` exception, in release mode only. When I run the app in debug mode instead all works good.

If the debugger in Release Mode is accurate, it crashes on this line of code:

```
- (void)initPersonsTableTableColumnMetadata:(CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata *)metadata count:(NSInteger)valuesCount
{
    personsTableColumnMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:valuesCount];
    NSAutoreleasePool *metadataPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < valuesCount; i++) {
        CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata aMetadata = metadata[i];
        NSValue *metadataValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&aMetadata objCType:@encode(CBTableColumnMetadata)];
        [personsTableColumnMetadata setObject:metadataValue forKey:aMetadata.columnKey];
    }
    FreeAndNil(metadataPool);
}


-(CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata)tableColumnMetadataForKey:(NSString *)aKey
{
    CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata theMetadata;
    NSValue *storedValue = [personsTableColumnMetadata valueForKey:aKey];
    if (storedValue) {
        [storedValue getValue:&theMetadata]; //here
        return theMetadata;
    }
}

- (void)addColumnsToPersonTable:(CBEditableTableView *)table withKeys:(NSArray *)keys andAutosaveName:(NSString*)autosaveName
{
    for (NSString *columnKey in keys) {
        CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata metadata = [self tableColumnMetadataForKey:columnKey];
        NSTableColumn *newColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:columnKey];

        NSCell *cell = nil;

        if ([metadata.columnKey isEqualToString:@"Dragging"]) {
            cell = [[NSImageCell alloc] init];

        } else if ([metadata.editType isEqualToString:[self editableButton]]) {
            cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
            [cell setAction:@selector(selectAndOpenEditLookup:)];
            [cell setTag:[metadata.editEntity intValue]];
            [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"edit-inlist-16x16.png"]];
            [(NSButtonCell*)cell setImageScaling:NSImageScaleProportionallyDown];
            [cell setTarget:self];
            [cell setTitle:@""];

        } else {
            cell = [[CBPaddedTextCell alloc] init];
            if ([metadata.editType isEqualToString:[self notEditableComboBox]]) {
                [cell setEditable:NO];
            }
        }

        [newColumn setResizingMask:NSTableColumnUserResizingMask];
        [[newColumn headerCell] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",metadata.columnHeader]];

        [[newColumn headerCell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail]; // or NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle

        if (metadata.minWidth > 0.0) {
            [newColumn setMinWidth:metadata.minWidth];
        }
        if (metadata.maxWidth > 0.0) {
            [newColumn setMaxWidth:metadata.maxWidth];
        }

        [newColumn setWidth:100.0];

        if (![metadata.editType length])
            if ([cell isKindOfClass:[NSTextFieldCell class]])
                [(NSTextFieldCell*)cell setTextColor:[NSColor grayColor]];

        [newColumn setDataCell:cell];
        FreeAndNil(cell);

        if (![metadata.editType isEqualToString:[self editableButton]]) {
            NSDictionary *bindingOptions =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSCreatesSortDescriptorBindingOption,
                                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSEditableBinding,
                                            nil];

            [newColumn bind:@"value" toObject:[table arrayController] withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", metadata.bindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
            [[newColumn dataCell] setEditable:YES];
        }

        [newColumn setIdentifier:columnKey];
        [table addTableColumn:newColumn];
        FreeAndNil(newColumn);
    }

    NSTableColumn *newColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Remove"];

    NSButtonCell *cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
    [cell setAction:@selector(removeEditableItem:)];
    [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"]];
    [cell setImageScaling:NSImageScaleProportionallyDown];
    [cell setTarget:self];
    [cell setTitle:@""];
    [newColumn setMinWidth:20];
    [newColumn setMaxWidth:20];
    [newColumn setWidth:20.0];
    [[newColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@""];

    [newColumn setDataCell:cell];
    FreeAndNil(cell);
    [table addTableColumn:newColumn];
    FreeAndNil(newColumn);

    [table setNeedsDisplay];
    [table reloadData];

    [table setAutosaveName:autosaveName];
    [table setAutosaveTableColumns:YES];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];


    NSArray * artistKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dragging", @"DisplayName", @"FirstName", @"LastName", @"SortName", @"ID", nil];
    [editableArtistTable setArrayController:artistsArrayController];
    [self addColumnsToPersonTable:editableArtistTable withKeys:artistKeys andAutosaveName:@"editableArtistTable"];
```

CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata

```
typedef struct _CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata {
    NSString *columnKey;
    NSString *columnHeader;
    NSString *bindingKeyPath;
    CGFloat minWidth;
    CGFloat maxWidth;
    NSString *editType;
    NSString *editEntity;
    BOOL     forbidEmpty;
} CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata;
```

Not sure why. Debug mode all works good.

**UPDATE**: Console log:

```
2014-12-17 16:13:20.580 *** Collection <__NSArrayI: 0xf60f0a0> was mutated while being enumerated.
2014-12-17 16:13:20.582 Colr (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x9711a343 __raiseError + 195
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x98bbda2a objc_exception_throw + 276
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x97119c0a __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 362
    3   Colr                     0x00165e16 -[CBEditItemWithOutletsBase addColumnsToPersonTable:withKeys:andAutosaveName:] + 149
    4   Colr                     0x00192413 -[CBEditItemWithOutlets windowDidLoad] + 343
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some investigation (you can see comments above) it turned out that the problem was in `initPersonsTableTableColumnMetadata:count:` method

The below line:

```
NSValue *metadataValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&aMetadata objCType:@encode(CBTableColumnMetadata)];
```

Should've been:

```
NSValue *metadataValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&aMetadata objCType:@encode(CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata)];
```

The @encode struct type were incorrect.
Therefore it crashed when trying to decode it back to an `CBEditPersonTableColumnMetadata` struct.

I'm still a little puzzled as to why the exception suggested that it was due to mutating the array while enumerating it, but the method that crashed was called from within the enumeration (even though it had no affect on the array's objects), and fixing the above resolved the crashes.